# The products of paths in a topological space is associative when they are not normilized?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

I am trying to understand the fundamental group of a topological space X and I have two questions. (First I write the definitions to be sure I understood them well.)
A path is a continuous map $\alpha:[0,r]\rightarrow X$. It is normalized if r=1. Otherwise, it can be normalized by $\alpha(rt):=\alpha_1(t)$ so that $t$ takes values in $[0,1]$.One can define the composition of paths as follows: 
\begin{equation}
(\alpha\cdot\beta)(t)=
\begin{cases}
      \beta(t), & 0\leq t\leq r_1 \\
      \alpha(t-r_1), & r_1\leq t\leq r_1+r_2
    \end{cases}
    \end{equation}
    and $\alpha(r_1)=\beta(0)$.

**Q.1** Could someone prove the associativity for say $\alpha, \beta,$ and $\gamma$ and tell me the pictorial interpretation of associativity?

(my attempt to answer due to Eric Wofsey's and Hurkyl's comments):
 $(\alpha\cdot\beta)\cdot\gamma(t)$ means firstly applying $\gamma$ and then applying the composition $(\alpha\cdot\beta)$.Hence:
\begin{equation}
(\alpha\cdot\beta)\cdot\gamma(t)=
\begin{cases}
  \gamma(t), & 0\leq t\leq r_3 \\
  \beta(t-r_3), & r_3\leq t\leq r_1+r_3\\
   \alpha(t-(r_1+r_3)), & r_1+r_3\leq t\leq r_1+r_2+r_3
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
and $\gamma(r_3)=\beta(0)$ and $\beta(r_1)=\alpha(0)$.
Therefore both are equivalent. 
    $\alpha\cdot(\beta\cdot\gamma)(t)$ means firstly applying the composition $\beta\cdot\gamma$ and then applying $(\alpha)$ to it.Hence:
\begin{equation}
\alpha\cdot(\beta\cdot\gamma)(t)=
\begin{cases}
  \gamma(t), & 0\leq t\leq r_3 \\
  \beta(t-r_3), & r_3\leq t\leq r_1+r_3\\
   \alpha(t-(r_1+r_3)), & r_1+r_3\leq t\leq r_1+r_2+r_3
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
  and $\gamma(r_3)=\beta(0)$ and $\beta(r_1)=\alpha(0)$.
 Therefore, $(\alpha\cdot\beta)\cdot\gamma(t)=\alpha\cdot(\beta\cdot\gamma)(t)$.

**Q.2** Also, I read in the book Knots and Surfaces by Gilbert ([here](https://books.google.com/books?id=1h_BmvjwZHAC&lpg=PA215&ots=gsWJpFyxcr&dq=associativity%20of%20normalized%20paths&pg=PA215#v=onepage&q=associativity%20of%20normalized%20paths&f=false)) that "the composition of normalized paths is not associative." Why is that?

Comment: Have you tried writing down what $(\alpha\cdot\beta)\cdot\gamma$ and $\alpha\cdot(\beta\cdot\gamma)$ are?

Comment: Even for normalized paths, the junction is not associative. It is associative up to homotopy with fixed edges.

Comment: @EricWofsey please take a look at my post now that I edited it.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli would you please explain more why is that?

Comment: You seem to have calculated $(\beta \cdot \alpha) \cdot \gamma$, not $(\alpha \cdot \beta) \cdot \gamma$.

Comment: @Hurkyl Thank you for pointing out my mistake. would you please also take a look at Q.2?

Comment: Normalised paths are paths $\alpha:[0,1]\rightarrow X$ with composition $(\alpha\cdot\beta)(t)$ defined to be $\alpha(2t)$ for $t\in[0,1/2]$ and $\beta(2t-1)$ for $t\in[1/2,1]$. Do the same calculations you did before, but with this new product and you will answer Q2.

Comment: It seems to me convenient,  and easier on students,  to have paths in a space $X$ to form a category. It is also more in keeping with the notion of path as a "journey"; different journeys often take different times.  This is done in Crowell and Fox "Introduction to Knot Theory" and my own "Topology and Groupoids". The treatments are slightly different otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This community wiki solution is intended to clear the question from the unanswered queue.

Q.1 Yes, your proof is correct.

Q.2 Normalised paths are paths $\alpha, \beta$ are composed by $(\alpha \cdot \beta)(t) = \alpha(2t)$ for $t \le 1/2$ and $(\alpha \cdot \beta)(t) = \beta(2t-1)$ for $t \ge 1/2$. Now let $\alpha = \gamma$ = constant path and $\beta$ be a non-constant path. Then $(\alpha \cdot \beta)\cdot \gamma$ is constant on $[1/2,1]$, but $\alpha \cdot (\beta\cdot \gamma)$ is not constant on $[1/2,1]$.